# Getting a smooth Poisson Distribution over a Histogram with Small Number of Bins

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting, poisson

I have a Poisson distribution of a background count which mostly contains counts equal to zero, I've fitted a Poisson distribution to this data and gotten the following result:

[image: Histogram for background data with Poisson distribution]

I have another dataset from a source which has higher count rates, in this case it works fine:
[image: Histogram for source data with Poisson distribution]

Here's my (inelegant) code in full;

```
mean_values = []
# obtaining results:
for a in data_arrays:
    dataset = globals()[a]
    cps_vals = dataset[:,1]
    max_cps = int(max(cps_vals))
    mean_name = a +"_mean"
    std_name = a + "_std"
    serr_name = a + "_serr"
    mean = globals()[mean_name] = np.mean(cps_vals)
    globals()[std_name] = np.std(cps_vals,ddof=1)
    globals()[serr_name] = globals()[std_name]/np.sqrt(len(cps_vals)) ## I used globals() so I could call in e.g. the background serr as the variable bg_serr.
    print(a,"mean:",globals()[mean_name],"sqrt(mean):",np.sqrt(globals()[mean_name]),"std:",globals()[std_name],"serr:",globals()[serr_name],"sqrt(lambda)/sigma =",np.sqrt(globals()[mean_name])/globals()[std_name])
    
    # plotting with Poisson:
    
    plt.figure()
    bin_edges = np.arange(0, max_cps+1.1, 1)
    histogram = plt.hist(cps_vals,density=True,bins=bin_edges)
    plt.xlabel("Counts Per Second")
    plt.ylabel("Probability of Occurence")
    pops = histogram[0]
    bins = histogram[1]
    
    maxidx = np.argmax(pops)
    maxpop = pops[maxidx]
    maxbin = np.max(bins)
    most_populated_bin = bins[maxidx]
    
    plt.plot(np.arange(0, maxbin), poisson.pmf(np.arange(0,maxbin), 
    np.mean(cps_vals)),c="black")
```

This is the relevant line for the Poisson plot:

`plt.plot(np.arange(0, maxbin), poisson.pmf(np.arange(0,maxbin), np.mean(cps_vals)),c="black")`

If I try to make the np.arange spacing smaller, I get ringing in the Poisson curves:

[image]
[image]

I think this is because it needs integer values of counts?

How can I produce a smooth Guassian curve for the background count? The one I'm getting doesn't look right.

Comment: you can only meaningfully evaluate the Poisson dsn at discrete values, for example this will show the 'ringing': maxbin = 20
plt.plot(poisson.pmf(np.arange(0,2*maxbin)/2,10))

Comment: poisson distribution is discrete so any smooth curve is misleading. I suggest drawing 'step' line, not a 'straight' line.

Answer (score 0):

```
mu = 15
r = poisson.rvs(mu, size=100000)
plt.hist(r, bins=np.linspace(0, 35, 36), alpha=0.5, label='counting process', ec='black', align='left')
plt.plot(poisson.pmf(np.linspace(0, 35, 36),mu)*100000)
plt.legend()
```

Gives:

[image]